# What is the proof that $|\ln (1-x)|\le 2|x|$ if $|x|\le \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove that
$$|\ln (1-x)|\le 2|x| \, \text{if} \, |x|\le \frac{1}{2}.$$
What I've got so far is
$$\begin{align*}e^{x}&=1+x+\dfrac{x^{2}}{2!}+\cdots\\1+x&\le e^{x}\\1-x&\le e^{-x}\\ \ln (1-x)&\le -x.\end{align*}$$
However, I'm stuck here since when I take the absolute value of both sides I get nonsense (well, not exactly, it holds only for $x=0$):
$$|\ln (1-x)|\le |x|$$
I don't know how to proceed in order to prove the inequality mentioned in the question.

**Edit:** Also, why is taking the absolute value of both sides (as it seems) forbidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$|\ln(1-x)|=\left|-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n\right|
\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x|^n}n\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty|x|^n=\frac{|x|}{1-|x|}$$
etc.?

Comment: So $(2-2|x|)|\ln (1-x)|\le 2|x|$. How to get rid of the factor of $(2-2|x|)$? I'm able to prove it only for $x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What's the size of $2-2|x|$ for $x$ in your domain?

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x\in [-1/2,1/2].$ By the MVT we have

$$\ln (1-x) = \ln (1) -\frac{1}{1-c_x}x$$

for some $c_x$ between $0$ and $x.$ Thus

$$|\ln (1-x)| = \left|\frac{1}{1-c_x}x\right|\le 2|x|.$$

We get the factor of $2$ on the right because $|c_x|\le 1/2,$ hence $1/(1-c_x)\le 1/(1-1/2)=2.$

Comment: Very helpful answer. I'm curious though, what should I do if $x$ was complex? Since the mean value theorem holds only for real numbers.